# Yosemite 10.10.3 asks for google password every week with 2 factor authentication

Tags: macos, password, two-step-authentication

I have two factor authentication enabled on my google account and I was really happy when Apple finally started to support that.

However there is a slight nuisance: OSX keeps asking for a password every week or so and I have to reenter the security code for two factor authentication.

The "Never ask on this device" option is nowhere to be found. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Google still considers some apps (including Apple's) to be [less secure](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?hl=en), as they call them. As a solution to be safe, they can force you to reauthenticate from time to time.

My solution, that I'm happy with so far, is to use their [App Passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) for every single app that is *less secure* and does this annoying reauthentication step.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a solution to this for a long time and haven't found something suitable. As noted by @michal, Google was requiring App Passwords for different apps in OSX but as of 10.10.3, that requirement has been removed.

*Note: If you have iOS 8.3 on your iPhone or OSX 10.10.3 on your Mac, you will no longer have to use App passwords to use 2-Step Verification.*[1](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)